# Spring Security hasAnyRole() working mechanism

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have developed a web using spring security to set the authorization, I mistakenly set the `hasAnyRole("ADMIN, INTERNAL")` instead of `hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "INTERNAL")`, but surprisingly it worked as expected, namely a user has only internal role was able to access the content that was restricted using `hasAnyRole("ADMIN, INTERNAL")` ;

**My question is** basing on the underneath implementation, using `hasAnyRole("ADMIN, INTERNAL")` instead of `hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "INTERNAL")` should not given a user that only has ROLE_INTERNAL access right, but in fact, it did, How is that possible ?

I using spring-security-config:4.1.1.RELEASE, the calling stack of hasAnyRole is something like this

```
    public ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry hasAnyRole(String... roles) {
        return access(ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.hasAnyRole(roles));
    }
```

then in ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.hasAnyRole(roles)

```
    private static String hasAnyRole(String... authorities) {
    String anyAuthorities = StringUtils.arrayToDelimitedString(authorities,
            "','ROLE_");
    return "hasAnyRole('ROLE_" + anyAuthorities + "')";
    }
```

Then in  StringUtils.arrayToDelimitedString(Object[] arr, String delim)

```
    public static String arrayToDelimitedString(Object[] arr, String delim) {
    if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(arr)) {
        return "";
    }
    if (arr.length == 1) {
        return ObjectUtils.nullSafeToString(arr[0]);
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            sb.append(delim);
        }
        sb.append(arr[i]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Seems rather obvious what's happening -
 `StringUtils.arrayToDelimitedString(authorities,"','ROLE_")`. What is your question?

Comment: just updated the post, add my question

Comment: "_My question is basing on the underneath implementation, using `hasAnyRole("ADMIN, INTERNAL") instead of hasAnyRole("ADMIN, INTERNAL")` should not given a user that only has `ROLE_INTERNAL` access right, but in fact, it did, How is that possible?_" - It's possible because you have read the code wrong. It does exactly what it's supposed to.

Comment: are you invoking hasAnyRoles() from your jsp?

Comment: no, hasAnyRoles() is not used in any jsp page